# Save Object using realm Inverse relationships Swift

Tags: swift, realm

I have problem when I save data using Realm database in Swift.

I have two entities called "MathSolutions" , "Folder". One folder can have multiple questions. One to Many relationships.

MathSolutions Entity

```
 class MathSolutions: Object {

    dynamic var question = ""
    dynamic var steps = ""
    dynamic var createdDate = NSDate()
    let solutions = List<Folders>()


    class func JSONInboundMappingDictionary() -> [String:String] {
        return [
            //"id": "id",
            "question"  : "question",
            "steps"     :"steps",
            "createdDate" : "createdDate",
            "solutions"     : "solutions"
        ]
    }
}
```

Folder class

```
  class Folders: Object {
    dynamic var folderName: String = ""
    var folders = LinkingObjects(fromType: MathSolutions.self, property: "solutions")

}
```

Another processing part

```
   let mathSolution = MathSolutions(value: ["question": answers.question,"steps":realmcrud.createJOSNString(answers),"createdDate":NSDate()] )
    realmcrud.saveMySolution(mathSolution,folder: folder!)



//MARK:-Save Solutions
func saveMySolution(mathSolutions:MathSolutions,folder: Folders){
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write{
        mathSolutions.solutions.append(folder)
        realm.add(mathSolutions)
    }
}
```

Created folder is ok working fine. problem is when I save `MathSolutions` I got below error.

I always get below error

`2016-10-12 15:39:36.234 JIT[92648:1964826] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'Invalid property name', reason: 'Property 'name' not found in object of type 'Folders''`

### EDIT

Calling create part

```
 let realmcrud = RealmCURD();
            //let folder = Folders(value : ["id" : realmcrud.folderNextID(),"folderName":self.enteredFolderName])
            let folder = Folders(value : ["folderName":self.enteredFolderName])
            realmcrud.createFolder(folder)
```

Create Folder DB file

```
   //MARK:-Create folder
func createFolder(folders: Folders){
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write{
        realm.add(folders,update: false)
    }
}
```

**My Requriment** is I have Folders & MathSolution entities, 
- I have list of folders or user can create new folder, thereafter they can save my math problems in selected folder from the list.

- When I saved, I got above issue.
- I achieved this requirement using primary key concept at the initial stage, it was working fine [it totally early stage, primary key concept means - having the `id` fileds in the `Folders` and the `MathSolution` entity class, give the folder reference using the id, i.e when I save problems, it goes to `MathSolution` table like `question , steps , id, createdDate` same like folder table ' `id, folderName`] **but** later I decided to go with object mapping that time I faced this issue. is it clear? any solution

Please any idea? please suggest

Comment: Have you stored `Solution` objects before, when the property `folderName` was actually called `name`?

Comment: Did you change your schema? If so, have you performed the migration? Could you also provide some code where `Folders` is created?

Comment: @ezcoding No. Initially I developed by using id and primary key, later my team suggested to go without primary key concept. So I changed the code, but I removed the application from emulator and installed again. I don't have anything called `name`

Comment: @Dmitry. I havent changed the schema name, but initially , developed with primary key concept with ID then later removed that part and add object mapping between two tables. I will edit my question and share the create folder code.

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not clear what is going on there, could you please share a full stack trace? or, even better, the example project that reproduces this issue?

Comment: @Dmitry My current issue this in the above question. I will tell you what is my requirement. I have `Folders` & `MathSolution` entities, I have list of folders or can create new folder, thereafter i can save my math problems in selected folder from the list. When I saved, I got above issue. I achieved this requirement using primary key concept but later I decided to go with object mapping that time i faced this issue.  is it clear? any solution?